# How to find IP:Port of incoming client in TCP Connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, go, ip, server

After receiving a connection from `conn, err := listener.Accept()`, I want to find the address of the client at the other end of the `conn`. I've tried doing this with `conn.LocalAddr()` and  `conn.RemoteAddr()` ([Documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn)). `.LocalAddr()` just gives the address of the server's process. `.RemoteAddr()` gives the right IP for the client but a very different port number from what I know the client to be binded to.
If it makes any difference, Im doing this with two separate processes running on the same machine. One is a client, one is a server. Any ideas as to how else I can find the correct IP:Port of the client? Am I to use either `LocalAddr` or `RemoteAddr`?

Comment: Why do you think the `RemoteAddr` port is wrong? It's very rare to initiate a connection with a defined local port.

Answer (score 7):

On OSX, using go 1.4 the host / port combo reported by `conn.RemoteAddr()` is correct when compared against netstat output.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net"
  "time"
)

func main() {
  ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  for {
    conn, err := ln.Accept()
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(conn.RemoteAddr())
    time.Sleep(time.Minute)
    conn.Close()
  }
}

$ go run foo.go
127.0.0.1:63418

$ netstat -an | grep 8080
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.8080         127.0.0.1.63418        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.63418        127.0.0.1.8080         ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks a lot! I guess it somehow didn't occur to me that just because my client is binded to a specific port doesn't mean it will be making outgoing connections via that same port.

Answer (score -4):

netstat -a 1 -f in the windows shell. I'm a command line guy, this works, write it to a file via redirect. This will rerun every second, the f is to resolve DNS name.